# How to replace full path name with only name in string?

Tags: c#, windows, string, replace

I'm using c# and want to put in string only name of data which have full name from location

Example I have in string this name : 
**D:\Users\admin\Documents\file.txt** , 
and want to have in string only **file.txt**

How to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the method [GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) of the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w) class :

```
String path = "D:\Users\admin\Documents\file.txt";
string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) will return what you need.

```
string fileName = @"D:\Users\admin\Documents\file.txt";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

`result` will be "file.txt".

Answer (score 2):

If you want with file extension use

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
```

If you want without file extension use

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Path.GetFileName` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

As aleroot has stated, you want to use the `System.IO.Path` class. Heres how you would use it:

```
string strFullFilePath = "D:\Users\admin\Documents\file.txt";
string strFileNameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFullFilePath);
```

I hope this helps.